# Ariadne-GraphQL - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'graphql.pyutils.undefined'

Tags: python, flask, graphql, ariadne-graphql

I am trying to import several libraries:

```
from ariadne import load_schema_from_path, make_executable_schema, \
    graphql_sync, snake_case_fallback_resolvers, ObjectType
```

But when running this I get this Error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'graphql.pyutils.undefined'
```

Before that I downgraded to a lower graphql-core version by using `pip install "graphql-core<3.1"`because I got this ImportError:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'PLAYGROUND_HTML' from 'ariadne.constants'
```

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Checking the source code of Ariadne v. `0.19.1`, the `PLAYGROUND_HTML` seems to be supposed to be used via an `ExplorerPlayground` class.

Try something like this:

```
from ariadne.explorer import ExplorerPlayground

PLAYGROUND_HTML = ExplorerPlayground(title="Cool API").html(None)

@app.route("/graphql", methods=["GET"])
def graphql_playground():
    return PLAYGROUND_HTML, 200
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue here.

I noticed `ariadne` `0.18` was not compatible with `graphql-core<3.1`.

Then I downgraded `ariadne` to `0.17`.

This way my server (I'm using Flask) runs on `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` and the playground is accesible on `http://127.0.0.1:5000/graphql`.

Not ideal but it worked out for me.